# How unbalanced would it be to change the duration of the Expeditious Retreat spell to "Concentration, until the end of a long rest"?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, house-rules, duration

I have been playing Baldur's Gate 3, and the rules in the computer game are slightly different than the ones in paper 5e.

One that I found surprisingly OK in the game was that the duration of several concentration spells, like for example *expeditous retreat*, was extended to run until the next long rest. (Not all of them -- *invisibility* or *fly* for example not).

A computer game plays differently than an in-person RPG; for example scouting with a familiar is a lot more cumbersome to execute than just saying that the familiar moves ahead of you 90 feet at the game table, so you do not do it as routinely, making the familiar a lot weaker.

But I still wonder: how unbalancing would it be to allow *expeditious retreat* in the tabletop game to have concentration until the end of a long rest, (or until concentration ends, for example when you are incapacitated by sleeping, using the *Xanathar* rule that sleep is considered giving you the unconscious condition)? Does anyone see any dangerous exploits this would enable?

Comment: Is it until the initiation or the end of the next long rest?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I think in the computer game that is the same -- I have not yet been ambushed in a long rest, so I cannot say, it seems the rest is just a single event that restores you when you start it. If it makes a difference for the paper game, I would say until end of the long rest (as a long rest does not really "happen" until its end).

Comment: Something to consider there, for clarity of how the feature works, you probably can’t concentrate while asleep, so concentration until the end of a long rest probably doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yes, good point being incapacitated would end it, as per normal concentration rules. So you could have it until you start sleeping in your long rest.

Comment: There are races for which a long rest does not include sleep (e.g. elves meditate, warforged just remain motionless but conscious)

Comment: Similarly, the Warlock Pact Aspect of the Moon seems specifically designed to allow certain concentration spells to last through a long rest (e.g., hex, for which concentration can last 24 hours when cast with a 5th level spell slot).

Comment: I don't think we can answer the "and other minor buff spells" part.  I think each spell is going to be a question of its own, and reasonable people can disagree about what constitutes a minor buff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely this won't be an issue for full casters, primarily because concentration is a very valuable resource that most casters won't want to tie up semi-permanently just to maintain a strong but situational movement bonus. That said, it might make *expeditious retreat* a more popular choice for the Magic Initiate feat or subclasses like the Eldritch Knight, where you may not intend to cast many other concentration spells anyway. Even so, I'm not sure it actually breaks the game or anything, since Rogues can do this anyway. At worst, it might make rogues and monks feel a bit less special as it steals one of their more visible combat abilities.

That said, this is likely to step on *longstrider*'s niche even if you boost *longstrider* to an "until long rest" duration. Longstrider has a smaller bonus, but lasts a lot longer and doesn't interfere with concentration. Take away the duration benefit, and that spell just isn't very interesting (unless it's combined with *expeditious retreat*, I suppose). Actually, increasing *longstrider* to an "until rest" duration sounds pretty interesting -- might encourage people to actually use the most boring movement spell, if only for boosting overland travel speed!

Comment: Thanks, I removed the "other minor buffs" to match the title question, I agree, that may make the scope a bit wide, and I did not expect an exhaustive treatment. I thought it might have an effect for low level combat against enemies without good ranged attacks too, as you could just perpetually dash away, and pelt them with firebolts. But I guess a thief can do that too, and most fights don't take that long, and I have not seen that tactic a lot in the wild. In the game you can have this and longstrider both (which even is a ritual!), for even more movement - both run to long rest.

Comment: Longstrider is also until long rest in BG3! Since it's *also* a ritual spell there, you can just cast it on everyone after a long rest and the only downside is that you have to keep it prepared... it's probably a bit too strong.

Comment: @Pyritie I am not sure about too strong, if bg3 got anything right it was movement, jumping and forcing movements. 10ft in 5e is almost nothing unless you have bonus action options to disengage or something, in bg3 it was often life or death and encourages usually unused spells. At least I thought, I didn't like the game too much otherwise.

Comment: @Pyritie can’t wizards just ritual cast *any* spell that they know?

Comment: @fyrepenguin In BG3 you have to prepare the spell to cast it as a ritual, and if you then reorganize your prepared spells to remove the ritual, it'll remove the effect.

Comment: Also in BG3 there are some limitations in some ritual spells and cantrips such as Find Familiar and Mage Hand, which can only be cast once per short rest.